# Understanding function form_for() in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently reading Beginning Rails 3.  I'm coming from PHP and trying to learn Ruby and Rails.  I'm looking at a _form partial and I have a few questions.  Specifically about the line:

```
    <%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
```

What is the purpose of having the @article object in there as well as what is the function of variable f?

thanks,
mike

Comment: Welcome to Ruby & Rails, I hope you enjoy it.  Here is a link that discusses some core ruby concepts around blocks/procs & lambdas (which is essentially what you are asking about): http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form_for` accepts a model so that it can do a few things for you under the covers:

- It will read any current values off of that model and populate them in the fields you specify
- It will generate the proper URL for that resource (assuming you're following conventions, otherwise you still have to specify it)
- It can display any validation errors on the model if you're displaying after a POST.

If you just want the tag helpers, there's also [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) and friends

Comment: I also might add that this tag is responsible for actually printing the <form> html tag.  Everything that is passed the the block (between form_for(@article) and end) is going to be placed inside the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

The `@article` is what the form is for (in this case).

The `f` is for creating individual form elements; it's a builder object yielded by `form_for`'s block.